# Google app engine: how to store and retrieve a single variable

Tags: python, google-app-engine, twitter

I'm new to app engine (and SO)...

I'm writing a twitter bot that replies to mentions. Wanting to remember the last tweet it replied to using since_id but im not sure of the best way to store that ID so the next time the page loads it can check it, reply to any since, and then overwrite and store  the new ID.

Do I use memcache for this?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're fine with losing the data, don't use memcache for data storage; it should only be used as a cache. The reason for this is that although you can set how long it should keep this data, it's documented that it can delete it at any time.

Create a datastore entity to hold the object.

example:

```
class LastTweet(db.Model):
    since_id = db.IntegerProperty()
```

Comment: So I can retrieve and overwrite that same object each time there's a new message?

Comment: Right; just save it with a key_name and use that name to retrieve it each time.